# Tail a log file and if match trigger an actrion

Tags: powershell, tail

I am currently using the following line of code to return the most recent line of a log via PowerShell

```
Get-Content -Path C:\folder\thisisalog.log -Tail 1 -Wait |
    Where {$_ -match "Remote_http"}
```

This works correctly and will write to the console each time a log that matches "Remote_http" is logged.

However what I would like to do is run another script when this is returned.
So far I have tried to add to a variable  and check if it is null with no luck and I have tried using `if` statements with no success.
Trying both of these the script runs indefinitely with no output to console or triigers.

I think it may be something to do with `-Wait` which is causing the issue.

Comment: Change `Where` to `ForEach-Object`, turn the `-match` clause into an if statement and run the code/script inside the if block

Answer (score 5):

just do it

```
Get-Content -Path C:\folder\thisisalog.log -Tail 1 -Wait | % {if ($_ -match "Remote_http") {write-host "run code here"}}
```

or directly into your where

```
Get-Content -Path C:\folder\thisisalog.log -Tail 1 -Wait | where {if ($_ -match "Remote_http") {write-host "run code here"}}
```